# NullreferenceException problem on DataSet.clear()

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I'm using values from a row on a datagridview, to build an image path to pass to a picturebox.

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow currentRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
    string valueJob = currentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    string valueBatch = currentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    string valueImmagine = currentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    string result = Octopus2.Properties.Settings.Default.DataPath + "\\" + valueJob + "\\" + valueBatch + "\\" + valueImmagine + ".jpg";   
    pictbox.ImageLocation = result;
}
```

The problem is, when i do a DataSet.clear() using another control, the code returns the following error: "NullreferenceException was unhandled by user code".

Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this code raise the Exception or the Clear()?

Comment: what is the link between "DataSet.clear() " and your code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot se DataSet.clear() in the code you have shown but if DataSet.clear() is giving this error then DataSet is null.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned before, the DataSet.clear() is called by another eventhandler called by a control, a reset button.
I solved the problem by doing this:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.RowCount >=1)
    {
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = new DataGridViewRow();
        currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
        string valueJob = currentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string valueBatch = currentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string valueImmagine = currentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

        string result = Octopus2.Properties.Settings.Default.DataPath + "\\" + valueJob + "\\" + valueBatch + "\\" + valueImmagine + ".jpg";

        pictboxImpegnativa.ImageLocation = result;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("good work.");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check if `currentRow.Cells[x].Value` could also be null. You should add another code that looks like this:

```
if (currentRow.Cells[n].Value != null) 
{
    // your code here
}
```

Trust me, there's an inner object you need to catch for nulls not just the one from `DataGridViewRow`.